# Maintain File Upload Control on Postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have gone through this article

http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Maintain%20File%20Upload%20Control/Article.aspx

But he add a literal control like `<GEN:FieldValue="ATCH_FILENM"/>`

so is there any option for us to use such a control to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use the standard `<asp:FileUpload>` control?

See this article: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/061116.htm